# Updating a Mysql table row using Java

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

When i try to update a table record like below i get an error

Method - 1:

```
String jsonText = "{"id":100,"nickname":"yash","name":"Rahul"}"
Statement st3 = con.createStatement();
st3.executeUpdate("UPDATE comment SET c_wt ="+c_newwt+",c_Jsonwt ="+jsonText+" WHERE c_id="+c_id);
```

And, when i do it this way it gets updated

Method - 2:

```
Statement st3 = con.createStatement();
st3.executeUpdate("UPDATE comment SET c_wt ="+c_newwt+",c_Jsonwt ="+"'{"id":100,"nickname":"yash","name":"Rahul"}'"+" WHERE c_id="+c_id);
```

I need to get the table updated using the Method 1. Can any one please solve my problem? Thanks.

Comment: "*When i try to update a table record like below i get an error*". Well then, please include the full stacktrace!

Comment: Your String is not well formatted in the first method.

Comment: This may sound silly, but are you meant to have a semicolon on the end of that first line?  Additionally as mentioned it's not well formatted.  Java isn't really my forte.

Comment: Syntax errors will do that.

Comment: what error you get can you show here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not containing the JSON with "" in the SQL, use the below.  You also need to escape the " marks in the JSON and add a semicolon to the String declaration

```
String jsonText = "{\"id\":100,\"nickname\":\"yash\",\"name\":\"Rahul\"}";
Statement st3 = con.createStatement();
st3.executeUpdate("UPDATE comment SET c_wt ="+c_newwt+",c_Jsonwt ='"+jsonText+"' WHERE c_id="+c_id);
```

Comment: How do you mean "dint work" - did you get an error?

Comment: ""+jsonText+"" -> this dint work, but '"+jsonText+"' worked :)

Answer (score 1):

There is some missing quotes : `'"+jsonText+"'`

```
st3.executeUpdate("UPDATE comment SET c_wt ="+c_newwt+",c_Jsonwt ='"+jsonText+"' WHERE c_id="+c_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest something like

```
String jsonText = "{\"id\":100,\"nickname\":\"yash\",\"name\":\"Rahul\"}";
Statement st3 = con.createStatement();
st3.executeUpdate("UPDATE comment SET c_wt ="+c_newwt+",c_Jsonwt =\""+jsonText+"\" WHERE c_id="+c_id);
```

It looks like a lot of quotes need escaping.